# Creating a Button that links a URL after input

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
<br>
   < button onclick="myFunction()">LOLNEXUS< /button>
    function myFunction () {
    var person = prompt ( "Please enter your summoner name", "");

    if ( person != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    "http://www.lolnexus.com/NA/search?name="+ person;
    }
```

My question is how do I have the name they enter added to that link and turned into a URL?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a

```
<a href="" id="demo">Custom link</a>
```

on your page.
Calling innerHTML on it would modify the content of the link, so the url will be only shown. To put this url as a link, you can use

```
document.getElementById("demo").setAttribute("href", "http://www.lolnexus.com/NA/search?name="+ person);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="" id="demo">Custom link</a>
```

`<button onclick = "myFunction()" > LOLNEXUS < /button>` // button

//function starts

```
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter your summoner name", "");

    if (person != null) {
        var url = "http://www.lolnexus.com/NA/search?name=" + person;
        $('#demo').attr('href', url); //Replace the url

    }
}
```